# How to read a text file using WinSCP .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, text-files, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I need to use WinSCP .NET assembly to look for text files containing a specific word in the file name and then extract some lines from these files. 
I know it's probably a basic question, but I've never used neither SFTP connection nor this library before and have no idea how to start the project. I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) to retrieve a list of files in a remote directory
- Iterate the list to find files matching your criteria (`.txt`?)
- Download the matched files to a local temporary file using the [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles)
- Read the temporary file and look for the contents you need

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..."
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    const string remotePath = "/path";
    // Retrieve a list of files in a remote directory
    RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

    // Iterate the list
    foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
    {
        // Is it a file with .txt extension?
        if (!fileInfo.IsDirectory &&
            fileInfo.Name.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            // Download the file to a temporary folder
            var sourcePath =
                RemotePath.EscapeFileMask(remotePath + "/" + fileInfo.Name);
            session.GetFiles(sourcePath, tempPath).Check();
            // Read the contents
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(tempPath);
            // Retrieve what you need from lines
            ...
            // Delete the temporary copy
            File.Delete(tempPath);
        }
    }
}
```

---

See also a similar (PowerShell though) example [Listing files matching wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_listing_files_matching_wildcard).

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.